Successful login but it is not executing function
I am trying to make the login do the function when the response is success, but for some reason it does not log the response but still logins into the site after you F5 and refresh it. Any help is appreciated as I am not good at this at all!
$(function() {
    var action = "";
    var form_data = "";
    $("#login").click(function() {
        $("#username").prop("disabled", true);
        $("#password").prop("disabled", true);
        action = $("#loginform").attr("action");
        form_data = {
            username: $("#username").val(),
            password: $("#password").val(),
        };
        $("#login").keypress(function(e) {
            if (e.which == 13) {
                //Enter key pressed
                $("#login").click();
            }
        });
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "?base=misc&script=login",
            data: form_data,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(response) {
                if (response.status) {
                    $("#loginform").slideUp("slow", function () {
                        $("#message").html(
                            '<script>location.reload();</script><div class="alert alert-success">Logged in. Reloading...</div>'
                        );
                    });
                } else {
                    $("#username").prop("disabled", false);
                    $("#password").prop("disabled", false);
                    $("#message")
                        .hide()
                        .html(
                            '<br/><div class="alert alert-danger">Wrong username or password</div>'
                        )
                        .fadeIn("fast");
                }
                console.log(response);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});


Are there any errors on the browser's development console?  In the browser's development tools, on the network tab, is the AJAX request made?  Is the server's response what you expect?  When you use the browser's script debugger to step through the code as it executes, what specifically happens?

It's almost always wrong to add an event listener inside another event listener. Each time you click on #login you'll duplicate the .keypress() listener.

Hello David, so when the response has failed, the development console will display the failed response and also execute the "wrong username or password" I seem to have only issues with when the response is suppose to be success, it does not seem to give any response.

You call location.reload() when it's a successful response. So you won't see the Logged in message because the page reloads before displaying that.

If you want the user to see the message, use setTimeout() to add a delay before reloading.

Hi Barmar, unfortunately the page doesn't even reload. That's what I'm also stuck on. Once you click login with a successful login it just stays. No reloading, no message, nothing. I will also add your suggestion as well!

Does DevTools Network tab show that a response was received? Does it look like valid JSON?

I do see the json in the network tab and it does show that a response is received. not sure why the success function doesn't not execute.

@Leech: When you use the browser's script debugger to place a breakpoint on the first line of the success function, is that breakpoint reached?  If you add an error function and place a breakpoint in there, is that reached?  (And if so, what is the error?)

There are some ways to fix that. But first I think it’s a great idea fix your code also:
$(function() {
    var action = "";
    var form_data = "";
    $("#login").keypress(function(e) {
       if (e.which == 13) {
         //Enter key pressed
         $("#login").click();
       }
     });
    $("#login").click(function() {
        $("#username").prop("disabled", true);
        $("#password").prop("disabled", true);
        action = $("#loginform").attr("action");
        form_data = {
            username: $("#username").val(),
            password: $("#password").val(),
        };
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "?base=misc&script=login",
            data: form_data,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(response) {
               // If you still want to debug the response var.
               console.log(response);
               if (response.status) {
                 $("#loginform").slideUp("slow", function () {

                 $("#message").hide().html('<div class="alert alert-success">Logged in. Reloading...</div>').fadeIn(“fast”);
                     setTimeOut(function () {
                        location.reload();
                     }, 3000);
                  });
                } else {
                    $("#username").prop("disabled", false);
                    $("#password").prop("disabled", false);
                    $("#message")
                        .hide()
                        .html(
                            '<br/><div class="alert alert-danger">Wrong username or password</div>'
                        )
                        .fadeIn("fast");
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});


Thank you, I appreciate the fix! It seems it may be another reason why the success function isn't able to execute, I am not very good at coding so I do not know!

You got any log on your console with this code?
